# Kotlin, Type Mistmatch Required Boolean Found Class<Class> *Issue Fixed itself*

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have been programming a small Chat Application and have come across the following error

> Type Mismatch 
>   Required Boolean 
>   Found Class

```
private fun fetchUsers() {
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()

                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("NewMessage", it.toString())
                    val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
                    if (user != null) {
                        adapter.add(UserItem(user))
                    }
                }

                view_newMessage.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
```

The error is occurring on the Following Line

```
val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
```

The error had only recently surfaced as before Today(25th April 2020) it was working fine

The user class is as follows

```
class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val profileImageUrl: String) {
    constructor() : this("", "", "")
}
```

The Database Structure is as Follows

```
"users" : {
  "p9fuXh6QiBdh50y7ysgm1xSNiiw1" : {
    "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/virdomessaging.appspot.com/o/images%2F44f1736d-581b-496d-89b3-3bdb72ab10b5?alt=media&token=8e4f03dc-4d58-48a6-9951-2daf3bb8f01a",
    "uid" : "p9fuXh6QiBdh50y7ysgm1xSNiiw1",
    "username" : "MattMcCann"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you let us know what `DataSnapshot.children` is?

Comment: `DataSnapshot.children` is just calling to the Firebase Database, allowing me to retrieve the Data and the ForEach is for every user record in the Users Table

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @MatthewMcCann we don't know about `it` if you let us know the type of DataSnapshot.children is iterable of which type of objects?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the Database Structure, in its JSON Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem this morning. In Tools, AVD Manager, on the virtual device that you are using, in Actions column, you have the option to Wipe Data. Clearing the data fixed my issue. 
Regards Martin

Comment: Thank-you for telling me if the issue arises again, I shall try your method